# Why am I getting error: Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key

I am quite new to SQL and learning by doing this exercise....

I'm working on a problem in MySQL and I cannot get my head around this error message... the Modules & Course_modules tables populated fine but the student_enrollment will not...even though I believe the foreign keys to be the same for student_enrollment and course_modules table but I am clearly missing something.

Please see the code below

```
CREATE SCHEMA `test`; 


# modules pathway 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.Modules (
    Module_ID INT(5) NOT NULL,
    Module_Code int(11) NOT NULL,
    Module_Name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Lecturer_Code INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Module_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Module_code) REFERENCES test.Course_Modules(Module_code)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.Course_Modules (
    Course_code int(11) NOT NULL,
    Module_code int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Module_code),
    FOREIGN KEY (Course_code) REFERENCES test.Course_info(Course_code)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

# students pathway
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.Students (
    student_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    student_code int(10) NOT NULL,
    Forename varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Middle_names varchar(30),
    Surnames varchar(30) not null, 
    DOB DATE not null, 
    PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_code) REFERENCES test.Student_enrollment(student_code)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.Student_enrollment (
    student_code int(10) NOT NULL,
    Course_code int(11) NOT NULL,
    enrollment_level int(5) null, 
    PRIMARY KEY (student_code),
    FOREIGN KEY (Course_code) REFERENCES test.Course_info(Course_code)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

#lecturer pathway
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.Lecturers (
    Employee_ID INT(11) NOT NULL,
    Employee_Code int(10) NOT NULL,
    Forename varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Middle_names varchar(30),
    Surnames varchar(30) not null, 
    DOB DATE not null, 
    PRIMARY KEY (Employee_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Employee_Code) REFERENCES test.Coordinators(Employee_Code)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.Coordinators (

    Employee_Code int(10) NOT NULL,
    Course_code int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Employee_Code),
    FOREIGN KEY (Course_code) REFERENCES test.Course_info(Course_code)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

#course info
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.Course_info (
    Course_code int(11) NOT NULL,
    Course_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Accred_Level INT(2),
    Employee_Code int(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (Course_code)
    #Foreign key(Course_code) references test.Course_Modules(Course_code)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Error message: Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'student_enrollment_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'Course_info'

Comment: You can't add an foreign key constraint on a non existing table. Change the order in which you are creating the tables. [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/8CfHT-k8) you have a working fiddle. More important take a look on [Conditions and Restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Ah makes sense. Thanks man

Comment: Add the FKs (using `ALTER TABLE`) _after_ `CREATEing` _all_ the tables.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll take that on board.